# Calculating a sum of several nested loops in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to calculate total  sum in nested ng-repeat. In console I get an error and total sum wrong. Link on code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2COhklgwusfNw7yNYZhi?p=preview). My template and js

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="container">

<div ng-repeat="key in goods">
    <h3>{{key.name}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="good in key.group">
        <h4>{{good.goodName}}</h4>
        <ul>
           <li>Count: <input ng-model="good.items" value="{{good.items}}" type="text"></li>
           <li>Times: <input ng-model="good.times" value="{{good.times}}" type="text"></li>
           <li>Sum: {{sum(good)}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="total">
    <h2>Total sum: {{total()}}</h2>
</div>

</div>
```

My js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){


$scope.allSum = 0;

$scope.sum = function(good) {
    $scope.allSum += good.items * good.times;   
    return good.items * good.times;
};

$scope.total = function() {
    return $scope.allSum;
};


$scope.goods = [

    {

        'name': 'name 1',
        'group': [

                    {
                        'goodName': 'good 1',
                        'items': '4',
                        'times': '2',
                        'sum': '8',
                        'id': '1'
                    },
                    {
                        'goodName': 'good 2',
                        'items': '2',
                        'times': '2',
                        'sum': '4',
                        'id': '2'
                    }

                   ]
    },
    {


        'name': 'name 2',
        'group': [

                    {
                        'goodName': 'good 3',
                        'items': '1',
                        'times': '10',
                        'sum': '10',
                        'id': '3'
                    },
                    {
                        'goodName': 'good 4',
                        'items': '3',
                        'times': '1',
                        'sum': '3',
                        'id': '4'
                    }

                   ]

    }




];

}]);
```

In console i have error: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] and wrong sum.

Comment: I dont think the [$rootScope:infdig] is coming from this code. As far as getting the wrong sum its probably because you are calculating strings instead of ints. Try $scope.allSum += parseInt(good.items) * parseInt(good.times);

Comment: Brian, It did not help me. Sum is wrong. I think the problem with duplicates. How can i fix this?

Comment: You are missing your closing div on your controller div. Is that just a typo?

Comment: you also define class twice in your controller div

Comment: Brian,it just a typo.

Comment: found the problem... see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your function runs twice. A much better and cleaner approach is to use a watch function that updates everything:

```
$scope.$watch('goods', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
        $scope.allSum = 0;
        angular.forEach(newValue, function(val, key) {
            angular.forEach(val.group, function(v, k) {
                v.sum = v.items * v.times;
                $scope.allSum += v.sum;
            });
        });
     }
}, true);
```

Now you can get rid of the sum and total functions completely. Then just update your html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="key in goods">
        <h3>{{key.name}}</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="good in key.group">
            <h4>{{good.goodName}}</h4>
            <ul>
               <li>Count: <input ng-model="good.items" value="{{good.items}}" type="text"></li>
               <li>Times: <input ng-model="good.times" value="{{good.times}}" type="text"></li>
               <li>Sum: {{good.sum}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="total">
        <h2>Total sum: {{allSum}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brian thank you! It helped! But now total sum not changed...it is 25)

Comment: Yea I noticed that. Rather than go all over the place and make the code way more complicated, I made you a watch function that works very good. Check out my edit.

Comment: No problem. And by the way, you don't need the value on your inputs when using ng-model. It doesn't hurt anything but it is ignored.